# error C2664 :cannot convert argument from 'Node<int>* ' to 'int'

Tags: c++, templates, type-conversion

Node.h:

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
class Node
{
  private:
     T m_Data;
     shared_ptr<Node<T>> pre_node,next_node;

  public:
     Node(T iData, Node* pre_ptr = nullptr, Node* next_ptr = nullptr) 
       :m_Data(iData),pre_node(make_shared<Node>(pre_ptr)),
        next_node(make_shared<Node>(next_ptr))
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Node.h"

int main()
{
   Node<int> head(1);

   system("pause");

   return 0;
}
```

I get an error when try to run the code:

```
 error C2664: 'Node<int>::Node(const Node<int> &) throw()' : cannot convert argument 1   
 from 'Node<int> *' to 'int'
```

Can someone explain the problem and the way to correct it?

Comment: _'cannot convert argument 1   
 from 'Node<int> *' to 'int''_ Yeah! You probably meant `Node<int> head(new Node<int>(1));`

Comment: nope,is Node<int> head(1) as in the main.cpp

Comment: you don't have a constructor for 'int'

Comment: I declare that as a template class, the T in the constructor are suppose to turn to int when i instantiate it as Node<int>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely the call to `std::make_shared`:

```
make_shared<Node>(next_ptr)
```

Here, the argument should be a `Node` or something that can be used to construct one (for instance, a `T` or specifically in your case, an `int`.) You are passing a `Node*`.

Don't pass a `Node*`. Pass an `int` or a `Node`. Or change your constructor to something like this:

```
 Node(T iData, shared_ptr<Node> pre_ptr = nullptr, shared_pre<Node> next_ptr = nullptr) 
   : m_Data(iData),
     pre_node(pre_ptr),
     next_node(next_ptr)
```

Comment: I changed the code to make_shared<Node<NodeDataType>> but still getting the same error

Comment: @balzex There is absolutely no reason that change would fix anything. You are the wrong the wrong argument to the function.

Comment: Thanks, i get it work by do the following changes in the constructor 
  
   pre_node(pre_ptr),  next_node(next_ptr)